# Ionic3 : the best way to import css from node_modules

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, import, ionic3

I am trying to import the .css from [full-calendar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-fullcalendar) package.

First, I created a new component **my-calendar** (html, scss, ts).

Then, I tried 3 different ways but only the last one worked for me:

1. Reference the file directly, as the documentation suggested, in the *index.html* (it does not work because the reference to node_modules is lost when you build the project)

   `<link href="node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`
2. Adding `@import "~fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.css";` in *my-calendar.scss*. If I am not wrong, this should add the style into *main.css*  when the project is being built (is not working)
3. Create custom copy config (copy.config.js)

   ```
   module.exports = {   
     ...   
     copyFullCalendar: {    
       src: ['{{ROOT}}/node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.css'],    
       dest: '{{BUILD}}'    
     }
   }
   ```

   and adding `@import "fullcalendar.min.css"`; into *my-calendar.scss*

**UPDATE:**
and adding `@import "fullcalendar";` into *my-calendar.scss*
to avoid compiler errors when use **ionic build --aot --minifycss --minifyjs**

I would appreciate if someone could clarify the best way and explain if I misunderstood some concept.

PS: Remember that I am working with Ionic3 and I am not using the Angular CLI.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

third method of yours will be the best way to implement , but it can be done in another way more like ionic.
You need to make use of the `includePaths` when configuring the custom path , as we are dealing with custom css, add `sass.config.js`  to local project folder where we configure custom includePaths like this

```
includePaths: [
    ....
    'node_modules/ap-angular2-fullcalendar'
 ],
```

In `package.json` scripts to include custom css configuration file, like this:

```
"scripts": {
    .....
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve -s ./config/sass.config.js"
 },
```

Only problem with this implementation is when you update `ionic-app-scripts` you have to compare the native `sass.config.js` file to the local file and check if there is anything changed.

This is a troublesome method and an issue was raised in [Github](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts/issues/777) but unfortunately they closed the issue with the following justification

> Configs are extended, so only include the fields that you're changing.
>   Everything else will inherit the defaults.

Answer (score 2):

As of @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0, it seems you'll still need to 
`@include FILE;` **somewhere**
See this [closed issue on app script's github](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts/issues/541)

I found that as of 
'Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2'
you have two choices insert your import in src/theme/variables.scss or src/app/app.scss.

For example in variables.scss

```
/* some declarations here */
@import 'insrctest';/*file sits in src/test/insrctest.scss*/
```

And in my custom.config.js

```
includePaths: [
'node_modules/ionic-angular/themes',
'node_modules/ionicons/dist/scss',
'node_modules/ionic-angular/fonts',
'./src/test', /* when the import above gets called, node-sass will look in here */
```